# Telling prof how summer went

Tags: advisor, email

I wanted ask how you guys would go about sending a prof/advisor about how a summer abroad trip went? I have a close professor that I have and would like send them a little email about my summer abroad trip.

Comment: What do you want to communicate, and why/what is your goal?

Comment: What kind of trip? Was it a business trip, such as a visit to a conference, a visiting research position, or a summer internship?

Comment: What is the issue?   Does the professor have some odd personality?

Answer (score 5):

Be polite, be brief, and if you have an "ulterior motive", be very clear about any points where you want a response or any specific information you want the person to remember (eg if you want them to write you a letter).

Example (I am clearly making up a lot of details, including that you've already asked this person to write you a letter, but this is just to give you an idea)

Dear Professor X,

I just wanted to let you know that I had a great and very productive trip to Hogwarts. I was able to collaborate with Prof McGonagall and we are preparing a manuscript about the applications of transfiguration to elliptic curves. I would be more than happy to send you a copy if you would be interested, especially if it would be useful for you to look at a copy when writing a letter of recommendation for graduate schools. Thank you as always for your advice and support.

Sincerely,

Lily